# Tin/aluminum foil a suitable method of stopping USB3 interference with 2.4GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb-3, interference

I wish to use USB3 to connect my hard drive with my server but it causes interference with Wi-Fi as the access point is fairly close to the hard drive (not much I can do about it).

Is there any safety concern with using tin/aluminum foil to cover the head of the USB3 cable connected into the server port and maybe the cable? Did anyone else try this before, and is it effective?

I should mention that the insulation on the cable is not broken and the wiring is not exposed.

Note: Yes, I have tried simply plugging the cable into a USB2 port and it works fine. But for reasons unrelated I want to use USB3.

Comment: Won't it be simpler to just buy a shielded/braided cable?

Comment: The USB3 to SATA adapter I'm using does not have a detachable cable.

Comment: A shielded USB3 extension cable?

Comment: The cable I was talking about is the cable that connects from the SATA/USB3 adapter to a USB3 port. Basically: HDD -SATA-> USB3/SATA adapter -USB3 cable-> USB3 port on server. There is no second extension cable. I don't know if it's shielded or not, there is also not much about the hardware details of the adapter. But I was getting interference; for example, while a PC was connected to a Wi-Fi network ssh'd into the server, plugging in the HDD via USB3 to the server slowed the ssh connection to a crawl (Took several seconds for characters to show up) and some devices simply didn't have signal.